# Use Twitter Advanced search to find retweets made by a single account?

Tags: twitter

I've been trying to find a way using Twitter Advanced Search to return retweets made by a certain user. I'm trying to use a 3rd party tool called Twools to pull just retweets using a search. I've tried using this query, but it doesn't seem to return any retweets.

```
from:username include:retweets
```

I'm not sure such a thing exists, but I'd love if there were something like

```
from:username onlyinclude:retweets
```

Is there any secret search syntax that might be usable?

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by "made by"? Is "username" the person who retweeted or the person who made the original tweet?

Comment: In this instance it would be all retweets of other users made by "username".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @AlexVong noted in the comments, you can find the new referential retweets by using:

```
from:username include:nativeretweets filter:nativeretweets
```

**Previously:**

It seems like the syntax for showing all the retweets by a user is supposed to be:

```
from:username include:retweets filter:retweets
```

However, it seems all of this search syntax is broken in "modern" Twitter, where retweets are treated as a reference to the original tweet, rather than a separate "RT @originaluser stuff and things" tweet from the retweeter. `filter:retweets` picks up any tweet that happens to contain the word "RT" anywhere in the tweet but *not* actual retweets anymore.

Comment: It may not work in Twitter proper, but it does happen to work in Twools when doing a Twitter search, which is pretty awesome.

Comment: @jbwharris `from:username include:nativeretweets filter:nativeretweets` seems to display recent retweets but not older retweets. Does anyone know of a way to display all retweets of a user?

Comment: @AlexVong are you able find a way to get old retweets also ?

Comment: @AlexVong - fantastic find. Works! How did you discover `include:nativeretweets` please if you don't mind sharing?

Comment: @thanks_in_advance I don't know if this is how they found out about it, but it is shown in the examples list in Twitter's documentation for TweetDeck https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/advanced-tweetdeck-features